# Post to facebook wall from an Adobe Air android application

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm currently developing a basic Adobe Air Flash Application which will let user's go through a calculator. Once the user has gone through the calculator I am storing the value in a variable.

Now what i want to do is:
1) Have a button to let the user login to facebook
2)Post a default message to their wall (they do not need to be able to edit or enter a message)
3)Logout

I am finding it very difficult to find any resources out their to help. I'm also not an advanced programmer by any means, any help greatly appreciated! Also, I am working in Flash, not flex if that makes any difference

EDIT: Why has this received 2 negative votes ? At least provide some feedback to let me know how i can improve my questioning, or why i'm doing this wrong in your eye's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var appId:String = "APP ID HERE";
var messageTitle:String = "title for the message";
var messageUrl:String = "Link to the application";
var messageDescript:String = "Whatever you'd like to say";
var appThumb:String = "Thumbnail here";
var redirectUrl:String = "Once a user shares the link, where to redirect them - for me this is facebook again so they can log out";

var URLString:String = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="+projectApId+"&link="+messageUrl+"&picture="+projectThumb+"&name="+messageName+"&description="+messageDescription+"&redirect_uri="+redirectUrl;

function shareIt(){

var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(URLString);

try{ navigateToURL(req,"_blank"); }

catch (e:Error){ trace(">> ERROR <<", e.message); } 

}
```

I'm surprised i couldn't find it, or didn't get an answer through here, considering its so easy in the end :)

Comment: This works. Do you know what to put in the redirectUrl to make it go back to the original application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to help you

check this website form facebook [facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) you should find anything you need there.

Comment: Thank you for replying obounaim, but no it doesn't, I'm looking for actionscript, what you have pointed me too is javascript .... I have looked through google for this, it just doesn't seem to be very well documented or have much already out there.

Comment: Yeah i'd imagine if you were better at code than myself that link would provide the help needed. I couldnt however get the swc linking to flash. Not too sure why i've done it with other API's like Google Maps.

But nonetheless, thank you for taking the time to respond obounaim, i have resolved the problem myself and the code is above if any1 else should need it